# What are these small brown curved seeds?

Tags: identification, seeds

I got a plastic bag of seeds from my friend in church, but I don't know which kind of plant they will grow into when they come out. Would you please identify this seed?

[image: This Seed that need to be Identified]

Comment: Hi! Would you please edit some more details into your question, and also  close-up pictures of a whole, and broken, seed. Are those hard or soft? Rough or smooth? About how big are they? Where do you live? Are you in planting season now? More details are always better, especially with identification questions! Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

They look like [Lunaria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunaria) (Money Plant) seeds to me. They could be one of many other species, but I'd bet on Money Plant. They're often traded because of their easy culture and their novelty factor. You won't know until you grow! 
[image]